# What is the best way to remove elements in an array from an Iterator?

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

I have an Array and an Iterator. Both will be in the same type, lets say Integer, and i want to remove the values in the array from the iterator. For example:

My Iterator: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

My Array: `2, 5`

Then 2 and 5 will be removed from the iterator. How should i do this?

**Edit:** who doesn't know much about programming gives down vote lol.

Comment: The Iterator will remove the elements from the underlying collection the iterator came from. Is this what you want?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  The statement  _"My Iterator: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`"_ seems to imply you believe the iterator contains that list.  This is not true, an iterator does not contain anything.  Second, if it's truly an array and not a collection, then "removing" something involves moving later elements.  Usually removing from a true array is done by making a new array that does not contain the removed elements.  Please clarify what you are trying to do by showing how the data structures are declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use -- like in many other languages available -- a filter.

In common collections there is already an [FilterIterator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/FilterIterator.html). With that you can filter the unwanted elemnets and work with the one passing the filter.

```
final List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(2,5);
Iterator<Integer> filteredIterator = new FilterIterator(yourIterator, new Predicate<Integer>() {
    public boolean evaluate(Integer object) {
        return values.contains(object);
    }        
});
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the code sample. But you should use a Set for the contains check

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient answer, but I'd tackle it with a for loop and run through your array. Then for each element in the array, run through your iterator until you get a match, then invoke the iterator.remove() function.